# How to set the UIBarButtonItem color

Tags: iphone

I want to Change the UIBarButtonItem Color,
which is the sub view of UIToolBar,

My problem is if i change the toolber tint color , the barbuttonitems color are changing automatically ,how can i differ them...

Comment: I found this answer and it helped me immensely. http://stackoverflow.com/a/11088805/183231

Answer (score 2):

Yes that's the behavior of UIBarButton. You need to make custom image and assign it to UIBarbutton. That's the only solution according to me.

Answer (score 1):

Just Use the below code:
[YourBarButton setTintColor:[UIColor blackColor]];