# Change to color of back button

Tags: ios, swift

When I configured a segue from a table view cell to another VC which embedded in a nav Controller, there was a little back button(blue color) in the nav bar, i did not add any bar buttons in my story boards, but i want its color to be white. I have tried the following code:(in my viewDidLoad() method)

```
UIBarButtonItem.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
```

and this:

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
```

or any other similar codes...they were all not working.
Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Try it in `viewDidLayoutSubviews` method

Comment: try to this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11079148/change-uipopovercontroller-color-and-back-button-color?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

If you set the global tint color in the storyboard, it will affect the color of the back button.

Comment: what about setting the navigation item's color directly? Like:     self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem.tintColor = [UIColor redColor];